# Boltzmann distribuition and excited atoms

Tags: statistical-mechanics, temperature, atomic-physics

If I have a gas in a box and bring the box to temperature $T = 1K$ for example, so that $E = kT = 8*10^-5 eV$, from the Boltzmann distribution I have a non-zero probability for excited states even if the difference in energy between the G.S. and the first excited level is much greater than $E$. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if I misunderstood but that's the point of having Boltzmann distribution (if you look up on wikipedia). The distribution tells that you don't necessarily have to be in the ground state due to thermal fluctuations at finite temperature.

The probability of the system in $i$-th state with energy $E_i$ relative to ground state with energy $E_0$ is 
$$\frac{p_i}{p_0} = e^{\frac{E_i-E_0}{k_b T}}$$